# VBA to fill or colour cells in a range

Tags: vba, selection, counter

Introduction
This macro applies a spread amount (EG Annual budget amount less total forecast) to the remaining forecast months, EG Say 3 months left in a year October, Nov and Dec each in different columns.
The user selects a row, triggers the macro, the then a different macro (not shown as all working fine) determines the spread factors per month and then calls the macro below to calculate the amount per month.
The Macro below is working fine as is, however i now need to colour the target cells. Hence i have tried 3 options to modify the code per below, however receive error messages as described below:

Existing Macro:

```
Sub CalcMonthlyAmounts_Bdgt()

For Each s In Selection
AccumAmount = 0
AB = Cells(s.Row, 39).Value 'Total Budgets column
BC = Cells(s.Row, 35).Value 'Total Actuals column
TotAmt = (AB - BC)

For counter = (13 - Range("NO_OF_MONTHS").Value) To 11


MonthlyAmount(counter) = (TotAmt * SpreadFactors(counter) /    SpreadTotal)
Cells(s.Row, counter + 21).Value = MonthlyAmount(counter) 

Next counter

Next s
End If
End Sub
```

Option 1 - Add the following WITH . END WITH statement above the row 'Next Counter'. This results in error code 1004

```
With Cells(s.Row, counter + 21).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = RGB(230, 162, 94)
        .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Option 2 - Add the following line above the row 'Next Counter'. This results in error code 1004

```
Cells(s.Row, counter + 21).Interior.color=RGB(RGB(230, 162, 94)
```

Option 3 - Declare the object range (Cells(s.Row, counter + 21)) with DIM and SEt. This Ended with error code 424

```
Dim cell_range as range
Set cell_range = Cells(s.Row, counter + 21)
```

Thanks for any ideas. Funny thing is that option 1 worked for a short time, then broke...it must be quite close!

Comment: For Each s in Selection, where did you specify what s and Selection are?

Comment: Actually, all of your variables, where are they declared?

Comment: Variables are declared on top of the module 1 (where these macros are written). The variables are as follows:    Dim TotAmt As Double, MonthlyAmount(13), AccumAmount As Double, SpreadTotal As Double, SpreadFactors(12)

Comment: s and Selection are not declared. Can you make a recommendation pls.

Comment: You should declare s as Range.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Cells(s.Row, counter + 21)
    .Value = MonthlyAmount(counter)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(230, 162, 94)
End With
```

Comment: thanks Tim. I tried this, however it provided same error msg 1004 on row beginning with.INTERIOR. Pls see my response to the declarations above..i am beginning to think this is the problem area!

Comment: What are the values of `s.Row` and `counter` when it fails ? Any merged cells?

Comment: Thanks Tim for your assistance! Despite the cells i am trying to modify being unprotected on a work sheet that is protected, by unprotecting the work sheet first, then applying this macro, then re protecting it, it now appears working.